# Copying variables for an array to another array with the array being a struct with chars

Tags: c, arrays, struct

First off Ill show you how I'm defining struct StudentRecord

```
typedef struct{
char SN[10];
char lname[20];
float GPA;
}StudentRecord;
```

Now the point of this is to read in information from a .dat file which this program does successfully but when I go to save the array that I have made (more on this below) it give me a very weird output this code has a 2 global variables

```
StudentRecord* studentRecordList;
int studentRecordSize;
```

the studentRecordSize is going to be the first input line from the file, the function for reading the files looks like the following.

```
void load_records(){

FILE* student_file = fopen("StudentRecordFile.dat", "r");
if(student_file == 0){
    perror("cannot open StudentRecordFile.dat in load_records");
}
//free existing student list
if(studentRecordList != 0){
    free(studentRecordList);
}
//get number of students in the list
fscanf(student_file, "%d",&studentRecordSize);


//create and load new student list
studentRecordList = (StudentRecord*)malloc(studentRecordSize * sizeof(StudentRecord));
int i;
for(i = 0; i < studentRecordSize;i++){
    fscanf(student_file,"%s %s %s %f", studentRecordList[i].SN,studentRecordList[i].fname,studentRecordList[i].lname,&studentRecordList[i].GPA);

}

fclose(student_file);
}
```

Now from the driver you are given 4 options to 0-exit(also saves to the file), 1-find(just a search through the array), 2-add(add another student to the array), 3-modify, 4-delete.

the function for adding a student to the array is where I'm getting my problem for some reason it is messing up my output file and changing all my GPA variables to 0.000000 and leaving random blank spaces throughout the document. Anyway here is what it looks like.

```
void add_record(){
char fname[20];
char lname[20];
char SN[10];
float GPA;

printf("Enter the Students first Name: ");
scanf("%s", &fname);
printf("\nEnter the Students last Name: ");
scanf("%s", &lname);
printf("\nEnter the Students number: ");
scanf("%s", &SN);
printf("\nEnter the Students GPA: ");
scanf("%f", &GPA);

StudentRecord* tempList;
tempList = (StudentRecord*)malloc(studentRecordSize * sizeof(StudentRecord));

int i;
studentRecordSize = studentRecordSize+1;
for(i = 0; i < studentRecordSize -1; i ++){
    tempList[i].GPA = studentRecordList[i].GPA;
    strncpy(tempList[i].SN, studentRecordList[i].SN,10);
    strncpy(tempList[i].fname, studentRecordList[i].fname,20);
    strncpy(tempList[i].lname , studentRecordList[i].lname,20);
}
printf("%f", &tempList[i].GPA );

free(studentRecordList);
studentRecordList = (StudentRecord*)malloc(studentRecordSize * sizeof(StudentRecord));

for(i=0; i < studentRecordSize; i ++){
    //adds the new student at the end of the array.
    if(i == studentRecordSize){
        strncpy(*studentRecordList[i].fname, &fname,20);
        strncpy(*studentRecordList[i].lname, &lname,20);
        studentRecordList[i].GPA = GPA;
        strncpy(*studentRecordList[i].SN, &SN,10);
    }

    strncpy(studentRecordList[i].fname, tempList[i].fname,20);
    strncpy(studentRecordList[i].lname , tempList[i].lname,20);
    studentRecordList[i].GPA  = tempList[i].GPA;
    strncpy(studentRecordList[i].SN , tempList[i].SN,10);
}
free(tempList);

}
```

Also if your curious here is what my save_records function looks like otherwise ignore.

```
void save_records(){
FILE* student_file = fopen("StudentRecordFile.dat", "w");
if(student_file == 0){
    perror("cannot open StudentRecordFile.dat in load_records");
}
fprintf(student_file,"%d\n",studentRecordSize);
int i;
for(i = 0; i < studentRecordSize; i++){
    fprintf(student_file,"%s\n%s\n%s\n%f\n", studentRecordList[i].SN, studentRecordList[i].fname, studentRecordList[i].lname, &studentRecordList[i].GPA);
}
}
```

If you need anything else let me know and ill be sure to add it, thanks.

Comment: Hmm, maybe someone will be more eager than me, but you could really make it easier to give good answers by 1.) make the code more readable using proper indentation, 2.) reduce it, ideally to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and 3.) state exactly what result you are getting and what result you are expecting instead.

Comment: Also, when you reach code of that complexity is a good point to learn  how to debug. This could be just by putting `printf` in your code to see if the values correspond to what you expect, to using a rubber duck or a veritable debugger. Others solving your problems will teach you much less than finding it yourself.

Comment: I feared that this might have been a problem just didn't want to leave anything important or slightly important out but ill look into making this a bit easier to read @FelixPalmen.

Comment: TL; DR; sorry about that. Not got to the chase soon enough.

Comment: Your scanfs are wrong. If you have char array, you don't take a pointer to that but use the array as a pointer. Why doesn't your compiler give a warning/error?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I've narrowed the problem more towards when I'm copying the data over to the temp, I did actually use a printf to do so. I feel it is my ignorance towards c pointers and how arrays actually work maybe I'm missing something there @JensGustedt.

Comment: @Thorx99 in that case, work with simple examples that will test each single point that you want to resolve.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen which scanfs the ones when I'm reading in new variables or the original load?

Comment: @Thorx99 if there's still some relevant misunderstanding about "pointers and arrays" in C (a very recurring topic btw) ... you *should* be able to reduce the problem to a minimal example. (Adding a new favorite link of mine here, too: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/))

Comment: `load_records` has correct `fscanf`, `add_record` has incorrect `scanf`s for strings. Please check your compiler settings and make sure all warnings are on.

Comment: Thor, @SamiKuhmonen was referring to the `scanf` statements with the `%s` format specifier, the argument should not have `&` before it.

Comment: @Thorx99 it's hard work, but everyone of us had to learn debugging (and this includes *isolating* a problem) at some stage. You can only benefit from it :)

Comment: @FelixPalmen Thanks for that link sometimes we all need a friendly reminder to take a step back and just work through it step by step. I now have that code working the way I want it to.

Comment: @Thorx99 glad to hear :) especially the "rubber duck" is surprisingly effective sometimes :)

Comment: Please replace all the `strncpy` guff with simply `tempList[i] = studentRecordList[i];` and so on. Structures may be copied using the assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

This code has some problems:

```
for(i=0; i < studentRecordSize; i ++){
    //adds the new student at the end of the array.
    if(i == studentRecordSize){    // <- This can never be TRUE !!!
        strncpy(*studentRecordList[i].fname, &fname,20); // Wrong
        strncpy(*studentRecordList[i].lname, &lname,20);
        studentRecordList[i].GPA = GPA;
        strncpy(*studentRecordList[i].SN, &SN,10);
    }

    // Should the code below be an else ?
    // If not you'll access outside tempList
    strncpy(studentRecordList[i].fname, tempList[i].fname,20);
    strncpy(studentRecordList[i].lname , tempList[i].lname,20);
    studentRecordList[i].GPA  = tempList[i].GPA;
    strncpy(studentRecordList[i].SN , tempList[i].SN,10);
}
```

Maybe you wanted to do:

```
for(i=0; i < studentRecordSize; i ++){
    if(i == (studentRecordSize-1)){
        // Add the new record
        strncpy(studentRecordList[i].fname, fname,20);
        strncpy(studentRecordList[i].lname, lname,20);
        studentRecordList[i].GPA = GPA;
        strncpy(studentRecordList[i].SN, SN,10);
    }
    else
    {
        // Copy from the temp list
        strncpy(studentRecordList[i].fname, tempList[i].fname,20);
        strncpy(studentRecordList[i].lname , tempList[i].lname,20);
        studentRecordList[i].GPA  = tempList[i].GPA;
        strncpy(studentRecordList[i].SN , tempList[i].SN,10);
    }
}
```

A more simple version of the add function could be:

```
void add_record(){
    char fname[20];
    char lname[20];
    char SN[10];
    float GPA;

    printf("Enter the Students first Name: ");
    scanf("%s", &fname);
    printf("\nEnter the Students last Name: ");
    scanf("%s", &lname);
    printf("\nEnter the Students number: ");
    scanf("%s", &SN);
    printf("\nEnter the Students GPA: ");
    scanf("%f", &GPA);

    StudentRecord* tempList;
    tempList = (StudentRecord*)malloc(studentRecordSize * sizeof(StudentRecord));

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < studentRecordSize; i ++){
        tempList = studentRecordList[i];
    }
    free(studentRecordList);

    studentRecordSize = studentRecordSize+1;
    studentRecordList = (StudentRecord*)malloc(studentRecordSize * sizeof(StudentRecord));

    for(i=0; i < (studentRecordSize-1); i ++){
        studentRecordList[i]  = tempList[i];
    }

    free(tempList);

    // Add the new record
    strncpy(studentRecordList[(studentRecordSize-1)].fname, fname,20);
    strncpy(studentRecordList[(studentRecordSize-1)].lname, lname,20);
    studentRecordList[(studentRecordSize-1)].GPA = GPA;
    strncpy(studentRecordList[(studentRecordSize-1)].SN, SN,10);
}
```

Comment: When I change it to `strncpy(*studentRecordList[i].fname, &fname,20)` it gives me the warning for the first argument of strncpy saying "makes pointer from integer without cast. and then another warning saying for the second argument of strncpy saying "incompatible pointer types".

Comment: `strncpy(*studentRecordList[i].fname, &fname,20);` is completely borked

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:
in save_records() open your file binary

```
 fopen(student_file , "wb");
```

then use fwrite to write the record

```
 fwrite( &studentRecordList[i] , sizeof( studentRecordList) , 1 ,   student_file );
```

It is also easier, if you can, to write the number of records to a separate file that you open text.

Comment: This is not really a good idea, about the only thing going for it is that it is fewer lines of code.